# Liquibase liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:

Tags: java, xml, spring, multithreading, liquibase

I tried to modify int column to varchar but it gives a lot of errors starting with this.

```
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private MerchantStatus status;

   public MerchantStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public Merchant setStatus(MerchantStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }
```

this is the column in domain. it is enum.

this is enum

```
public enum MerchantStatus {
    ACTIVE("merchant.status.active"),
    PASSIVE("merchant.status.passive");

    private String key;

    MerchantStatus(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

this is liquibase confg

```
<column name="status" type="INT"/>
```

i tried to change here. or i added this inside 20160616145216

```
<modifyDataType
                        columnName="status"
                        newDataType="varchar(255)"
                        tableName="merchant"/>
```

but it did not work.

> 2 change sets check sum    |
>   classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160616145216_create_merchant.xml::1466077959485-1::
>   (generated) is now: 7:5fb40924426396399804bb2cb7f74852
>   |
>   classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160720101800_load_data.xml::0000000000001-2::
>   (generated) is now: 7:aa0084f69ca5301ef48cfb97beb41582
>   |       |      |
>   liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
>   f    |      2 change sets check sum     |
>   classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160616145216_create_merchant.xml::1466077959485-1::
>   (generated) is now: 7:5fb40924426396399804bb2cb7f74852
>   |
>   classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20160720101800_load_data.xml::0000000000001-2::
>   (generated) is now: 7:aa0084f69ca5301ef48cfb97beb41582
>   |   |     at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:215)
>     |   at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:208)
>      |  at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
>       |     at
>   liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:434)
>      |  at
>   liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:391)
>       |     at
>   net.infoowl.fraud.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:63)
>   1     |   at
>   net.infoowl.fraud.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:49)
>        |    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     |   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

also

> rror: Unknown name value [0] for enum class
>   [net.infoowl.fraud.domain.util.MerchantStatus]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [0] for enum
>   class [net.infoowl.fraud.domain.util.MerchantStatus]

furthermore

also when i do diff after this

<

```
modifyDataType
                        columnName="status"
                        newDataType="varchar(255)"
                        tableName="merchant"/>
```

it still doesnot convert to varchar

Comment: You seem to have modified a liquibase changeset  that has already been executed by Liquibase. Don't do that: revert to the previous version, and add a new changeset.

Comment: is it good for changeset? also when i do diff after this 

<modifyDataType
                        columnName="status"
                        newDataType="varchar(255)"
                        tableName="merchant"/>

it still doesnot convert to varchar

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: I want to see string value in front end but despite it says  rror: Unknown name value [0] for enum class [net.infoowl.fraud.domain.util.MerchantStatus]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [0] for enum class [net.infoowl.fraud.domain.util.MerchantStatus]

İ also added to the question.

Comment: Changing the type of a column from int to varchar won't magically change all the values from 0 to 'ACTIVE' and from 1 to 'PASSIVE'. You need to add this to your changeset, too.

Comment: it doesnot change anything because in database tab of intelj, it seems always int datatype. I restarted a lot of times but did not change

Comment: Have you fixed your xml files as I said you should? Do you still have an error message from Liquibase?

Comment: Thanks it wrked :) i can accept if you answer sir.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to have modified a liquibase changeset that has already been executed by Liquibase. Don't do that: revert to the previous version, and add a new changeset.

Then add another changeSet (or task) transforming all the 0 in that column to 'ACTIVE', and all the 1 in that column to 'PASSIVE'.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

```
  config/liquibase/changelog/20211227120229_added_entity_Product.xml::20211227120229-1-data::jhipster was: 8:d9bea6afc2902ce60cdfa54e82d248c4 but is now: 8:e353c8335afd112dfef95e3e95562f56
```

I am using jHipster to create the entities (db tables) and its related screens and other files. Which is handled by jhipster very well.
I modified one of the existing table structure and added new column in it.  Since then i started getting this error. I didn't modified the liquibase xml files manually. it was done by jhipster script. The solution that worked for me is to modify the MD5SUM manually in the table DATABASECHANGELOG using below command.

```
update DATABASECHANGELOG set MD5SUM = '8:e353c8335afd112dfef95e3e95562f56'
where MD5SUM = '8:d9bea6afc2902ce60cdfa54e82d248c4';
```

After this update it solved my problem however the column which i was added the last was not present in the table. So i needed to add that manually.

Answer (score 0):

Do a select on DATABASECHANGELOG and you will figure it out.

```sql
SELECT * FROM DATABASECHANGELOG;
```

If liquibase already processed one file you can't change this file anymore... unless you go on this DATABASECHANGELOG table and delete the last line that have your filename, them you can edit it and run again.

Depending on what you are doing maybe you need to do it twice, one to rollback your changes and another to make the right changes.